# How do I programmatically manipulate files on a shared drive without mapping?

Tags: c++, qt

I want to be able to delete and move files and folders located on a shared drive. The path would be something like \\some-pc\folder\

Due to the number of shared drives, mapping is not really an option.

Currently my program uses rename to move shared folders and their contents to a local folder, but when given a unc path, this fails. I can read the file. I'm testing using a shared folder from my own PC, so I should have the proper permissions.

I've been using Qt libraries, and TR2 filesystem.

Comment: Create symbolic link using the network ip address ,without requiring to map drive letter

Comment: Why does the program fail while accessing the directory/files via UNC? Is there and error, specific reason? For instance if that is about very long path, than we can deal with it.